# Article usage in "Sally has a good knowledge of English Grammar"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Thank you for your assistance. Which of these is correct?

> 1. 1. Sally has good knowledge of English Grammar in business.
>    2. Sally has a good knowledge of English Grammar in business.
> 2. 1. Sally has good knowledge of English.
>    2. Sally has a good knowledge of English.
> 3. 1. Sally has good knowledge of English Grammar.
>    2. Sally has a good knowledge of English Grammar.

Grammarly tells me all are correct.

Thank you so very much
Ken

Comment: You'd probably sound more fluent if you said "Sally has a good **grasp** of English."

Answer (score 2):

> Sally has good knowledge of English Grammar in business. Sally has a
>   good knowledge of English Grammar in business.

The above sounds awkward to me. How about: Sally has excellent command of Business English.

> Sally has good knowledge of English. Sally has a good knowledge of
>   English.

These are fine.

> Sally has good knowledge of English Grammar. Sally has (a) good
>   knowledge of English Grammar.

These are fine, too. I am fairly certain *grammar* doesn't need to be capitalised. I also think the (a) is unnecessary. Sally has good knowledge of English grammar. However the (a) is not wrong, either.

Is this a resumé or letter of recommendation?  If so, I suggest, " Sally has excellent/ a good command/ of Business English." Or, "Sally is eloquent in her use of Business English."

Comment: I would definitely use the phrase "business English."

Comment: @Robusto *grasp* is a perfect word for this.